# Select button and turn on others and reset other buttons in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a Pyqt5 GUI that displays Video using UDP streams

there are buttons that activate certain buttons 
as (SD1 or SD2 or SD3 will activate TP1 and TP2)
and Source 1 will activate TP5 and TP6 and so on

after clicking on SD1 the TP1 and TP2 will be active and if we clicked on TP1, it will show a certain UDP stream on the right side with the name of the program.

but when I try to click another SD or Source I like to have the old state of the button to be reset and the video to stop and to reset all the buttons,
so I don't have many buttons clicked and enabled at the same time.

here is the code:

```
#######################################  Important Libraries ##################################
import vlc
import os
import sys
import threading
from QLed import QLed
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl, QSize, QPoint, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QLCDNumber


class MainProg(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MainProg, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")

        self.setFixedSize(1280, 768)

        self.setStyleSheet("")
        self.setWindowTitle("video player ")
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.mediaplayer = self.instance.media_player_new()

        #################              The Test Points LEDs              ######################

        self.TPL1 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Round)
        self.TPL1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 500, 35, 25))

        self.TPL3 = QLed(self, onColour=QLed.Orange, shape=QLed.Round)
        self.TPL3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 525, 35, 25))

        ######################## Test Points Geo ##############################################

        self.Testpunk1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.Testpunk1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 460, 31, 31))
        self.Testpunk1.setObjectName("TP1")

        self.Testpunk2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.Testpunk2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 530, 31, 31))
        self.Testpunk2.setObjectName("TP2")

        self.Testpunk5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.Testpunk5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 490, 31, 31))
        self.Testpunk5.setObjectName("TP5")

        self.Testpunk6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.Testpunk6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 550, 31, 31))
        self.Testpunk6.setObjectName("TP6")

        ##########set text

        self.Testpunk1.setText(("TP1"))
        self.Testpunk2.setText(("TP2"))

        self.Testpunk5.setText(("TP5"))
        self.Testpunk6.setText(("TP6"))

        ############################      The Video and frame  #################################

        self.videoframe = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)
        self.videoframe.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(850, 40, 391, 291))
        self.videoframe.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.videoframe.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)

        self.vboxlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vboxlayout.addWidget(self.videoframe)
        self.mediaplayer.set_hwnd(int(self.videoframe.winId()))

        ########################################################################################
        ########################## SD and HD buttons############################################

        self.EspSD = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self, text="SD1", checkable=True)
        self.EspSD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 170, 31, 32))
        self.EspSD.setObjectName("SD")

        self.DeuSD = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self, text="SD2", checkable=True)
        self.DeuSD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 220, 31, 32))
        self.DeuSD.setObjectName("DeSD")

        self.DeupSD = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self, text="SD2", checkable=True)
        self.DeupSD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 270, 31, 32))
        self.DeupSD.setObjectName("DpSD")

        ##########################source  buttons############################################

        self.IntS = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self, text="Source5", checkable=True)
        self.IntS.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 170, 65, 32))
        self.IntS.setObjectName("5")

        self.AstD = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self, text="Source6", checkable=True)
        self.AstD.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 220, 65, 32))
        self.AstD.setObjectName("6")

        self.IntSdep = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self, text="Source7", checkable=True)
        self.IntSdep.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 270, 65, 32))
        self.IntSdep.setObjectName("7")

        ################################### The Main Window Labels ############################

        self.CurrentPro = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.CurrentPro.setFont(QFont('Arial', 10))
        self.CurrentPro.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 55, 140, 35))
        self.CurrentPro.setText("Current Program :")

        self.CurrentProL = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.CurrentProL.setFont(QFont('Arial', 10))
        self.CurrentProL.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 55, 155, 35))

        #################################### The Main Programm Functions ######################


        self.Testpunk1.clicked.connect(self.on_tp_clicked_Enc)
        self.Testpunk2.clicked.connect(self.on_tp_clicked_Enc)

        self.Testpunk5.clicked.connect(self.on_tp_clicked_Mux)
        self.Testpunk6.clicked.connect(self.on_tp_clicked_Mux)

        self.current_button = None
        #self.process = QtCore.QProcess(self)

    def on_tp_clicked_Enc(self):
        self.TPL1.setValue(True)


        if self.EspSD.isChecked():

            urls_map = {

                self.Testpunk1: "udp://@239.168.1.6:1113",
                self.Testpunk2: "udp://@239.168.1.7:1117",


            }
            url = urls_map.get(self.sender(), "")
            if url:

                self.play(url)

                self.CurrentProL.setText("Program4")


        if self.DeuSD.isChecked():

            urls_map = {

                self.Testpunk1: "udp://@239.168.1.6:1123",
                self.Testpunk2: "udp://@239.168.1.7:1127",


            }
            url = urls_map.get(self.sender(), "")
            if url:
                self.play(url)
                #self.current_button = self.sender()
                #self.current_button.setEnabled(False)
                self.CurrentProL.setText("Program5")


        if self.DeupSD.isChecked():

            urls_map = {


                self.Testpunk1: "udp://@239.168.1.6:1121",
                self.Testpunk2: "udp://@239.168.1.7:1125",

            }
            url = urls_map.get(self.sender(), "")
            if url:
                self.play(url)


                self.CurrentProL.setText("Program6")


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_tp_clicked_Mux(self):
        self.TPL3.setValue(True)  # the LED ON code

        if self.IntS.isChecked():

            urls_map = {

                self.Testpunk5: "udp://@239.168.2.6:2113",
                self.Testpunk6: "udp://@239.168.2.7:2123",

            }
            url = urls_map.get(self.sender(), "")
            if url:
                self.play(url)

                self.CurrentProL.setText("Program3 Source3")


        if self.AstD.isChecked():

            urls_map = {

                self.Testpunk5: "udp://@239.168.2.6:2117",
                self.Testpunk6: "udp://@239.168.2.7:2127",

            }
            url = urls_map.get(self.sender(), "")
            if url:
                self.play(url)

                self.CurrentProL.setText("Program4 Source4")

        if self.IntSdep.isChecked():

            urls_map = {

                self.Testpunk5: "udp://@239.168.2.6:2113",
                self.Testpunk6: "udp://@239.168.2.7:2123",

            }
            url = urls_map.get(self.sender(), "")
            if url:
                self.play(url)
                self.CurrentProL.setText("Program4 Source5")

    def play(self, url):

        print('the url arrived')
        self.media = self.instance.media_new(url)
        self.media.get_mrl()
        self.mediaplayer.set_media(self.media)
        print('last step before video viewing')
        self.mediaplayer.play()

        #self.TPL1.setValue(False)  # the LED ON code
        #self.TPL2.setValue(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainProg()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

##############################   End of the Code  #########################
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one button to be checked at a time you can use a QButtonGroup to manage the state of each button. By default the button group is exclusive so you just need to add the buttons.

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    . . .
    group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
    for btn in [self.EspSD, self.DeuSD, self.DeupSD, self.IntS, self.AstD, self.IntSdep]:
        group.addButton(btn)
```